# Android Studio App Edited images not showing up in gallery

Tags: android

I created a simple android app for adding frames and cropping images, now after the editing is done the pictures are saved in android root>app folder but non of these pictures show up in the gallery, here is My code

```
    /**
     * Create a File for saving an image or video
     */
    private File getOutputMediaFile() {
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted

//        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
//                + "/Android/data"
//                + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
//                + "/Files" + Global.AppFolder);

        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "/" + Global.AppFolder);


        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!root.exists()) {
            if (!root.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        String mImageName = "MI_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        mediaFile = new File(root.getAbsolutePath(), mImageName);
        return mediaFile;
    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return uri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String s = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_data"));
            cursor.close();
            return s;
        }
    }
```

By the way I am a newbie and don't have a lot of experience with android coding so detailed answers and references(for further learning) shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should send a broadcast to media scanner

Comment: `pictures are saved in android root>app folder` What do you consider to be the root app folder?

Comment: Sorry but there is no code that saves an image to file or writes something to file. Post that code please.

Comment: How did you check that the files are created? Except for starting the Gallery app.

Comment: I checked it through the file manager :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these code after you save the image

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

The Media Scanning is only done when the system Bootup. So you need to tell the media scanner to re-scan the files.

Comment: You can change the location to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + Global.AppFolder

Comment: I don't think it will work as I have rebooted the device 2-3 times already and it didn't show anything

Comment: Try this option its working perfectly for me. And in 1000+ other mobile phones. Because i recently uploaded an app with this method and more than 1k people are using it. @DanielS

Comment: Ok I replaced the code 
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "/" + Global.AppFolder); 
with
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + Global.AppFolder 

Should I add the broadcast code too and If Yes then where ?? Just below the save image code or somewhere else ?

Comment: @DanielS Add this code just after you save the image

Comment: Still not working and I am unable to post the whole code here so You can see if I made some other mistake :(

Comment: @DanielS did you check weather the saved image is showing in the file manager ?

Comment: No it wasn't working so I reverted back to the original code and the problem persists. If You could move this discussion to chat we can sort it out, It would be a great help

Comment: @DanielS yes came in chat

Answer (score 1):

try this add below code after saving image

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "title");
values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "description");
values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
values.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, root.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US).hashCode());
values.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, root.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.US));
values.put("_data", root.getAbsolutePath());
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```