# Image saved by the app doesn't show up in the gallery

Tags: image, flutter, dart, flutter-image

I trying to create a whatsapp status saver in flutter. I trying to save the whatsapp status. I created a folder statuses in `/storage/emulated/0/statuses/` and The process of copying goes well. But that Image is not shown in the gallery app.

So I even Tried storing it in `DCIM/Camera` still it doesn't show up there. But when the copy the same image using file explorer then that image shows up in gallery app. I think something is wrong with the image properties.

The code used to save is here.

```
saveFile(filePath) async {
    String newFilename;
    File originalFile = File(filePath);
    Directory _directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (!Directory("/storage/emulated/0/statuses/").existsSync()) {
      Directory("/storage/emulated/0/statuses/")
          .createSync(recursive: false);
    }
    String curDate = DateTime.now().toString();
    newFilename = "/storage/emulated/0/statuses/VIDEO-$curDate.jpg";

    await originalFile.copy(newFilename).then((value) {
      print("Saved: " + newFilename);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change a media, you should tell the device to re-scan. This [image saver plugin](https://github.com/hui-z/image_gallery_saver) will notify the Android OS about the media that is saved.

If you don't want the plugin, you can use platform channels to write native code yourself.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

This issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663886/android-studio-app-edited-images-not-showing-up-in-gallery) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32672).

Comment: It seems to be a java code. Is there any resources or documentation for flutter

Comment: Take a look at the Github issue I mentioned on the answer please.

Comment: You don't mention any flutter code in that github issue. Please help me by providing the code please.

Comment: You should notify the OS about the media changes. Dart code can not do such thing, it is an Android spesific protocol.

Comment: Then what will be the solution for it?

Comment: A plugin or method channel.